# Is this function holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z)=(z-z_0)^mg(z)$

with $f(z) $ holomorphic at $z_o$ and $g(z_o) \neq 0$

How do I show that $g(z)$ is holomorphic at $z_0?$

I could write $g(z)=\displaystyle \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_o)^m}$ but then there is a discontinuity at $z_0$ so I can't use the quotient rule. I'm not in fact at all clear that this is holomorphic at $z_0$ given the discontinuity.

This is the solution to the question i'm trying to follow.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g$ is not necessary holomorphic at $z_0$, look this example $f(z)=(z-z_0)^2=(z-z_0)^3g(z) $ where $g(z)=\dfrac{1}{z-z_0}$ if $z\neq z_0$ and $g(z_0)=1$

Comment: Ok, so the solution is wrong? It's just this question appeared in an exam so it's highly unlikely there is a mistake in the solution.

Comment: In your piece; it is written that: $f$ is holomorphic and has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$ this mean that $f(z)=(z-z_0)^mg(z)$  and $g$ is automatically holomorphic.